# Responsive Tumblr videos not working

Tags: javascript, iframe, video, tumblr

I'm trying to make videos on my Tumblr theme responsive. I am using `fitvids.js` to resize Vimeo and YouTube embeds. However, it won't work with Tumblr's native video player.

The Tumblr native video player uploads an iframe at a fixed width — I can change this, but then the formatting of the controls are very wonky (they must depend on the fixed height or width).

Also, the iframe `src` is hidden (`about:blank`), and Tumblr must do something custom to replace it:

```
<iframe width="500" height="281" src="about:blank" id="tumblr_video_iframe_87978936100" class="tumblr_video_iframe has_lightbox" data-origin="ckone-dev.tumblr.com" data-width="500" data-height="281" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" seamless="" style="display:block;background-color:transparent;overflow:hidden;">
</iframe>
```

Is there a solution to access an API for this video player, or at least change some of the contents of the iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use fitvids.js, you can use the [`padding-top` trick](http://blog.sproutvideo.com/how-to-make-your-videos-responsive.html):

```
.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
}

.videoWrapper iframe{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

And then this goes in the Tumblr template:

```
<div class="videoWrapper">{VideoEmbed-500}</div>
```

You can see it in action on [this tumblog](http://mikehacks.tumblr.com/post/84782180977/fountain-of-flavor-with-kipkay)

**NOTE:** that `56.25%` is the result of 9/16, that means that **the videos are fixed at the ratio 16:9.** If you plan on having square videos or any other ratio, like 4:3

1. apply a hashtag like **#fourthirds**
2. make sure you have `{TagsAsClasses}` on the `.videoWrapper` element

   ```
   <div class="videoWrapper {TagsAsClasses}">{VideoEmbed-500}</div>
   ```
3. add rules like this one:

   ```
   .fourthirds {
       padding-bottom: 75%; /*video is 4:3, therefore 3/4 = 0.75 = 75%*/
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Also, this won't work if using YouTube or Vimeo embeds via the {Video} template tag — that wraps them in a second iframe. I does work, however, if they're inserted as a text post.

Comment: That's why you need to use `{VideoEmbed-500}`, not `{Video-500}`. [It's confirmed](http://mikehacks.tumblr.com/post/86858788257) to work with YouTube videos as well.

Comment: Ah okay. What's the actual difference? The documentation says lightbox, but I don't see one on either tag.

Comment: Yeah the documentation is not clear, but the difference I found was that `{Video-500}` is the same as `{VideoEmbed-500}` plus some fixes for people who can't code. :D I use the latter simply because I don't want Tumblr to add unnecessary elements.

Comment: Thanks, you've been a great help. I  checked this morning and Tumblr no longer seem to be double embedding videos (they were doing it with both Video/Video-embed standard yesterday). Not quite sure what's going on!

Comment: Yeah recently I've seen changes in the "Customize Theme" panel, they're definitely tinkering with it. Hopefully they fix the whole ordeal because it's a huge hack. Pages spit out of Tumblr are impossible to validate because they add their code all over the place—and that's just one of the issues.

Comment: Just to clarify `{Video-500}` and `{VideoEmbed-500}` have no effect on how a video is embed. One plays the video on the page, the other play it in a lightbox, that's all. I love this solution, but it fails if the video ratio is not `4:3`. `fitvids.js` use the same solution, but works out the correct ratio based on the iframe width / height.

Comment: @mikedidthis That's not completely correct: YouTube videos may output the same code, but not Tumblr videos. Have a look at [this tumblr](http://bfredit.tumblr.com), open its source and see that the Tumblr video embed code is completely different and the resulting iframe will be in a `div`. —— As for the solution, yeah that's a limitation, but as I specified in the answer, you just have to specify the ratio in an hashtag and create a rule for it.

Comment: @bfred.it Sorry, I was trying to clarify that the codes themselves don't effect how the video is processed on Tumblr's back end, I probably worded it wrong. Again, its a great solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Save your sanity!**

I am adding this for reference and sanity. There are two key parts to making **Tumblr's own videos** responsive and not breaking your layout.

**Tumblr Video Variable**

When picking the video variable size, pick the one that is smaller than the video embeds parent. For example, if the parent is `300px` wide, use the variable: `{VideoEmbed-250}`.

Anything larger than the parent, will play havoc with your layout and end up breaking it, [visual example](http://i.imgur.com/TZwvF61.png).

**Fluid Videos**

As suggested, we need to use some sort of `padding-top` trick to make video embeds fluid / responsive. Using a set value for `padding-top` is limited as the ratio of each video may differ.

Alternatively, you can use `fitvids.js` with the following custom selectors:

```
$('.video-wrapper').fitVids({ customSelector: "iframe[src*='tumblr.com'], iframe[src='about:blank']" });
```

**References**

- Tumblr Video Variables - https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#video-posts
- Fluid Videos - http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-elastic-videos
- FitVids.js - https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js