# responsive tumblr video doesn’t work on mobile

Tags: video, mobile, responsive-design, tumblr, fitvids

In a tumblr theme I’m developing I use fitvids.js to make videos responsive.

All the common embeds (YouTube, Vimeo etc.) work like a charm.

I edited FitVids.js to support Tumblr video uploads (the tumblr video player). It’s behaving correctly on desktop, but it doesn’t work on mobile devices. The picture gets cropped and the play button is too big and exceeds the video container. You can’t play the video at all.

On this page it works, but I just can’t figure out how: http://mikehacks.tumblr.com/post/86858788257

my html is:

```
<div class="video-container">
  <p>{VideoEmbed-700}</p>
</div>
```

the video-container is only for adding some margin:

```
.video-container {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084703/responsive-tumblr-videos-not-working) but I depend on fitvids,js and I can’t expect the user of adding tags for aspect ratios. Also this won’t work with uncommon aspect ratios. Sorry for starting a new question; I’m not able to comment yet.

I’m really stuck with this, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Fitvids.js only seems to support a handful of video sources. If it's not compatible with Tumblr videos you have to look for something else or try to edit its code. The technique used on that tumblog is exacty what's described in that other StackOverflow question and it works with user-defined tags.

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly! I thought there’s maybe some javascript that makes the tumblr videos work on mobile. I’m gonna try to find an alternative or edit the code. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it is possible to setup FitVids to handle a custom video vendor. That said, it's not going to work in this case. On mobile, Tumblr does not serve a iFrame for the video. Instead, it serves an anchor link, which I now see that you noted in your answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Responsive Tumblr videos not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084703/responsive-tumblr-videos-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the tumblr videos to work on mobile – still using fitvids. It’s fairly simple but maybe someone will find this useful:

Since the tumblr video player has a whole different markup on mobile devices (it’s just a link to the video) it is clear fitvids will do nothing with that.

I used this simple CSS to tweak the tumblr videos only on touch devices:

```
.touch .video-container a {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

(I got rid of the p tag around the {VideoEmbed-700} because it caused the video to don’t play at all.)
The touch class is generated by Modernizr in case you wonder.

This way you don’t have to deal with tags for the aspect ratio!